# Resource allocator implementation

Tags: c++

I have a class A which is a collection of resource sets:

```
class A
{
    public:

        int getResourceSetCount() const;
        ResourceSet & getResourceSet(int index);
}
```

Moreover, I have a class B. It is used to allocate resources **within single** resource set.
Instance of this class cannot be copied and it looks like:

```
class B
{
    public:

        B(ResourceSet &resourceSet);

        Resource & getNextAvailableResource();
        int getAvailableResourceCount() const;


    private:

        B();
        B(const B &b);
        B & operator = (const B &b);
};
```

Now, I would like to implement a class C which will allocate resources **within all** available
resource sets, for example:

```
class C
{
    public:

        C(A &a);

        Resource & getNextAvailableResource();
};
```

Looks simple, right? But class B must be used for allocation within single resource set.
How to implement it when dynamic allocation (and STL) is not available and class B is protected from copying?

I would be very grateful for any kind of help.

Thanks,
Toreno

Comment: Does a `ResourceSet` "know" what instance of `B` is responsible for allocating to/from it?

Comment: Well, `B`'s can't be copied (or moved), so who owns them?  Can `C` own them?  Does `B` know which `ResourceSet` it is responsible for allocating?

Comment: Actually, only `B` "knows" how to allocate a resources in single `ResourceSet`. `C` can access class `A` to obtain all `ResourceSet`'s. But `C` can use only `B` to allocate resources in each single `ResourceSet`.